# Java- MySQL: Barcode scan to alter field in db

Tags: java, mysql, session, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am new to Java and MySQL, and I want to build my first app. So, I run into a few problems at the start. Two of them to be precise...

I want to make an app (for free), to support a local Board game club, and here is the catch.

The club wants to use Barcode scanner to read barcode in their member's membership cards. This should alter a field in their database, which is 'bit' type, corresponding to member being in the club, or not (with 1 being active, and 0 being away).

Other thing is, the member should be 'active' for the whole day, and his 'activity' should reset at the end of a day. 
I was thinking of making it a session, but how do I make it expire at the exact time?

Now, I have looked for answers in other questions, but have found nothing of use...

I am here for further clarifications if needed... 
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The barcode scanner is, for the most part, just a keyboard replacement. Instead of typing the code by hand, the scanner will send the keystrokes for you. You don't really need to do anything about it.

I assume the barcode represents member ID. When your application reads a barcode, it should then do something like this: `update members set active=1 where member_id = xxx`, with `xxx` being the barcode.

At the end of the day, you want to check all members out. You'll do something like this: `update members set active=0 where active=1`. Depending on your situation, you can either make a button to run this action, or you can make a cron job/task schedule that will run at some fixed time.

Comment: Yes, barcode represents Members ID. 
So, you say I need to make a button, and run the reset manually (I am a total noob for cron job/task scheduling).

I may look it up, and maybe work it out :) thank you, this have been helpful

Comment: Depends on what you want. You can even combine both, i.e. you have a scheduled job running every day at 11:59 PM, and a button you can click any time. There is one catch though: if your application stops working or you forget to press the button, the members in the database will remain checked in. For this reason, I would prefer to use a datetime column, say `last_check_in_time`, then you can always know that the member is checked out when current time is more than X hours after `last_check_in_time`.

Comment: never thought of that... thank you... time is irrelevant for the club... but date would be great addition.
I guess I can even record the dates, so the club can monitor how active every member is... :)